# How do I add an expression if it's a string?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a calculator program that has the features of addition, subtraction, and the notation X^ which means X^2. I'm completely lost and I don't know what to do. This is the code I have so far and an example of an expression I'm trying to solve.

```
1000 + 6^ - 5^ + 1;
```

and my code is

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sum;
    char answer, num, sign, add = '+', minus = '-';
    cin >> answer;
    string str;
    str += answer;

    while (cin >> sign)
    {
        if (sign == '^')
        {
            str += add + answer;
        }
        else if (sign == '+')
            {
                cin >> num >> sign;
                if ((cin >> sign) == '^')
                {
                    str += add + num + add + num;
                }
                else
                {
                    str += add + num;
                }
            }
            else if (sign == '-')
            {
                cin >> num >> sign;
                if ((cin >> sign) == '^')
                {
                    str += minus + num + minus + num;
                }
                else
                {
                    str += minus + num;
                }
            }
            else if (sign == ";")
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
                {
                    int digit = str[i] - 48;

                }
            }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't directly operate with that input, you need to parse it first.

Comment: How do I parse it?

Comment: Break up the string into tokens, analyze the tokens to see what they represent, and act accordingly. Token `1000` represents an integer, so convert it to an `int`.  Token `+` represents addition, so perform addition. Token `6^` represents an `int` 6. Token `^` squares the previous `int`. And so on. Parsing strings (searching for characters/substrings, extracting characters/substrings, etc) is a very fundamental skill you need to have, so I suggest you focus on honing that skill.

Comment: Building a `std::string str;` string from the input string doesn't seem helpful. What you actually want is to do the number operations the input describes.

Comment: `lex` and `yacc` (or `flex` and `bison`) are tools which help with this sort of thing. They have a learning curve which could make them overkill for this simple program if you're not already familiar with them, but they are nice for more complicated parsing tasks. It also depends on whether your goals are to learn simple string and number manipulation, to learn effective tools, and/or to get this specific program working.

Comment: Infix to postfix conversion and evaluation using stack: http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~hutchins/csci241/eval.htm

Comment: This shows a few ways to tokenize a string in C++; I recommend the one using getline. https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-split-strings-in-cpp